# Laravel simple template issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello people not sure what the problem is.. ....

here is my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('logout', function()
{
  return View::make('logout');
});
```

If i use link like this `<a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}">Log out</a>` it does not work .. but it works if i write it like this `<a href="logout">Log out</a>` same problem with css file .... this `{{ HTML::style('/css/style.css') }}` does not work but ...but this work `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` i think its not loading  laravel template system correctly........any ways to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blade templating to work, your file need to end with `.blade.php`, not just `.php`.

Comment: I think it's a 404 error, probably due to the configuration (apache and .htaccess)

Comment: @Marwelln so we have to configure routes.php to `return View::make('logout.blade');` ???

Comment: @Friend, no. `View::make('logout')` and then you have file `app/views/logout.blade.php`.

Comment: @Marwelln yes it seems to be working.. but in this case.. how do we include include php file?? iam sure it does not both `include('blade.logout.php')` && `include(logout.php)`